# How do I rank data in descending order while ignoring blank cells?

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api, ranking

I have a formula which will rank all of the data in a column correctly and ignores blank cells EXCEPT when the value in one of the ranked cells is 0.  Then all of the cells in the column with a 0 value AND all of the blank cells in the same column are ranked equally.
[Ranking Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhVNG.png)

To get my values in column "G" I'm using: `=if(isblank(E2),"",sum(F2:F7))`

To rank them I'm using: `=IF(ISNA(RANK(G2:G7,G$2:G$61)),"",RANK(G2:G7,G$2:G$61))`

I need the blank cells to be ignored even when one of the ranked cells has a value of 0.

1. I thought that maybe something in the formula used to calculate the values in column "G" was the issue so I deleted the formula in the blank cells (G20:G25 & G26:G31). Nothing changed.
2. I modified the ranking formula in column "H" by adding "<>" like so,

`=IF(ISNA(RANK(G2:G7,"<>",G$2:G$61)),"",RANK(G2:G7,"<>",G$2:G$61))`

but that just left H2:H7 blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging `G2` to `G7`, `G8` to `G13`, ... and then use the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(RANK(G2,G$2:G$61)),"",RANK(G2,G$2:G$61)).
```

[image]

Comment: I did as you suggested but it still didn't change anything.  I also tried using the formula from your pic without success.

Answer (score 0):

Since your condition is for values in column E to be blank, why do you not simply reuse that?
`=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",IF(ISNA(RANK(G2:G7,G$2:G$61)),"",RANK(G2:G7,G$2:G$61)))`

[image: Result without 0]
[image: Result with 0]

Comment: *sigh*  Thank you.  Such a painfully obvious solution.